# Complex matrix logarithm discontinuity by solving inverse Fourier integral by alternative method to FFT

Tags: matlab, matrix, fourier-transform

NOTE: This code is a piece of code I am using for a master's thesis, so I do not expect someone to do the work for me, but I gladly accept suggestions of any kind.

However, I am trying to get the model in this paper implemented using a Fourier transform-based method alternative to the classical FFT, namely the COS method presented in this paper.

The Fourier transform denoted with $\Psi$ (or characteristic function in probabilistic terms) to be implemented is this
$$
    \Psi(u;\tau) = 
        \exp\left(
             \mathrm{Tr}[A(\tau)\Sigma_{0}] + C(\tau) + iuY(t)
        \right)
$$
[NOTE: in the code I intentionally did not include the term $iuY(0)$] where the functions $A(\tau)\in M_{n}$ and $C(\tau)\in\mathbb{R}$ are
$$ 
    A(\tau) = A_{22}(\tau)^{-1}A_{21}(\tau)
$$
with
[image]
where $\gamma = iu$, $\mathbb{I}$ the identity matrix and
$$
C(\tau) = 
    -\frac{\beta}{2} \mathrm{Tr}
    \left[
         \log A_{22}(\tau) + (M^T + 2iuRQ)\tau
    \right]
    + iur \tau
$$
(references equations (5) p. 5, (14) and (15) pp. 7-8 of the [paper](https://www.dse.univr.it/documenti/RapportoRicercaEst/allegato/allegato975769.pdf)).

The COS method for computing the inverse Fourier integral is based on this relation
$$
f_{2}(x) = 
    \frac{1}{2}A_{0} 
    + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} A_{k} 
    \cos\left(k\pi \frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)
$$
$$
A_{k} = 
    \frac{2}{b-a} 
    \Re\left[
         \varphi\left( \frac{k\pi}{b-a}\right)
         \cdot \exp\left( -i\frac{ak\pi}{b-a}\right)
    \right]
$$
where $\varphi$ denote Fourier transform (references equations (9) and (11) p. 4 of this [paper](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/mf/users/oosterle/oosterlee/COS.pdf)).

Now, in the scalar function for $C(\tau)$, it is necessary to evaluate a (complex sense) matrix logarithm $\log A_{22}(\tau)$ for each argument of the Fourier transform, and this creates numerical discontinuities (to make a short story, every time a complete turn of the logarithm branch is made).

Now, one way to resolve this discontinuity is to implement the algorithm in this [paper](https://people.lu.usi.ch/gruberp/ElicitingASmile.pdf) (algorithm page 12) the "Matrix Rotation Count Algorithm." Essentially, the algorithm involves evaluating the complex logarithm by diagonalizing $PDP^{-1} = A$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues and correcting for each argument of the transform the imaginary part of the complex logarithm.

Now, look at the code I attached to the end of the question. In this code you find:

- the function `getRecoveredDensityByCOS`: implements the inverse Fourier integral (equations [9] and [11] of the COS paper)
- the function `chf_bs`: implements the Fourier transform (or characteristic function) of a model known as Black and Scholes (it is simply the Gaussian density characteristic function). I use this to debug the code.
- the function `chf_wmsv2`: implements the Fourier transform (basis) of the WMSV model
- the function `chf_wmsv`: implements the Fourier transform of the WMSV model corrected with the "Matrix Rotation Count" algorithm (the subject of the question).

Now, if you run the code for `cf_bs` (for all $t$) and for `cf_wmsv2` and `cf_wmsv` (for $t < 0.2$) there are no problems and everything works fine.

The main problem is when the coefficients of the cosine series are calculated, that is, when this line of code is executed

```
A_k = 2 / (b - a) * real(cf(u) .* exp(-i * u * a));
```

As I said, If you run the code for small times $t<0.2$ there is no problem, but when you try for times above $t>0.2$ here is the problem

[image]

Essentially, do you think I made a mistake in implementing the algorithm to correct the discontinuity of the complex logarithm or is there some other reason related to the numerical evaluation of the Fourier transform that causes me this problem.

As I said at the beginning, I don't expect anyone to solve the problem for me (because I recognize that is too much to ask) but any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Here I attach my code

```
clear varibles; close all; clc

% ------------------ %
%   Market Params
% ------------------ %
S0 = 100;      % Initial stock price
r = 0.05;      % Risk free rate 
q = 0;         % Dividend yield
t = 0.1;        % Time to maturity

% ------------------ %
%    Model Params
% ------------------ %
sigma = 0.25;        % Volatility

beta = 3;    % Role of Feller condition
M = [-3.0, 0.0; 0.0, -3.0];         
R = [-0.7, 0.0; 0.0, -0.7];    
Q = [0.25, 0.0; 0.0, 0.25];   
Sigma0 = [0.01, 0.0; 0.0, 0.01];  % Initial variance 


% Characteristic function
cf_bs = @(u) chf_bs(u,t,r,q,sigma);
cf_wmsv = @(u) chf_wmsv2(u,t,r,q,M,R,Q,Sigma0,beta);


% ------------------------------------------ %
%  Plot Fourier transform in Complex plane
% ------------------------------------------ %
u = linspace(-100,100,10000);
y = cf_wmsv(u);
figure(1)
plot3(u,real(y),imag(y),'LineWidth',1.5)
grid on
xlabel('u'); ylabel('\Re(\Psi)'); zlabel('\Im(\Psi)')
title('WMSV Fourier transform')


% -------------------------- %
%        COS settings
% -------------------------- %
% Domain for the density f(x)
x = linspace(-1.5,1.5,1000); 
% Define the COS method integration range
L = 12;   
a = - L * sqrt(t);    b = + L * sqrt(t);   

%%{
% Density
N = 2^16;   % number of sums in cosine expansion
fx_bs = getRecoveredDensityByCOS(cf_bs,x,N,a,b);
% fx_wmsv = getRecoveredDensityByCOS(cf_wmsv,x,N,a,b);


% --------------------------------------------------- %
% Plot density recovery (Inverse Fourier transform)
% --------------------------------------------------- %
figure(2)
plot(x,fx_bs,'linewidth',1.5,'Marker','o') % for BS
% plot(x,fx_wmsv,'linewidth',1.5,'Marker','o') % for WMSV
xlabel('x',FontSize=12); ylabel("f_{X}(x)",FontSize=12)
grid on
%}



function resu = getRecoveredDensityByCOS(cf,x,N,a,b)
    % Compute the cosine series expansion of the probability density function.
    % 
    % Literature: see the paper by F. Fang C. W. Oosterlee [2008] "A Novel 
    % Pricing Method for European Options based on Fourier-Cosine Series 
    % Expansions".
    % 
    % INPUTS 
    % cf :     Characteristic function (given as a function)
    % x :      Evaluation point
    % N :      Number of grid points
    % a :      Lower bound for inverse Fourier integral  
    % b :      Upper bound for inverse Fourier integral 
    %
    % OUTPUT
    % resu :   Probability density function approximation 
    
    i = complex(0,1); 
    % Index for Fourier grid
    k = 0:N-1;
    % Cosine argument
    u = k * pi / (b - a); 
    % Compute A_{k} cosine series coefficients approximation
    A_k = 2 / (b - a) * real(cf(u) .* exp(-i * u * a)); 
    % Correction for the first term
    A_k(1) = A_k(1) * 0.5; 
    % Final calculation
    resu = A_k * cos(u' * (x - a)); 
end


% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Here we compute the Fourier transforms (aka characteristic functions)
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------- %
% Black Scholes
function cf = chf_bs(u,t,r,q,sigma)
    i = complex(0,1);
    % Drift correction term
    mu = (r - q) - 0.5*sigma^2;
    % ChF for the Black Scholes model
    cf = exp(i*u*mu*t - 0.5*sigma^2*u.^2*t);  
end

% Heston Wishart Stochastic Volatility
function cf = chf_wmsv(u,t,r,q,M,R,Q,Sigma0,beta)
    i = complex(0,1);
    cf = zeros(1,length(u));
    % rot = [0, 0]; 
    % ---------- step (3) -----------% 
    % Initialize the number of rotations
    rot = zeros(2,length(u));
    mki = zeros(2,length(u));     
    for k = 1:length(u) 
        w = u(1,k);
        % ---------- step (3) -----------% 
        % Compute A22 matrix 
        MATEXP = expm(t*[M, -2.0*(Q'*Q); ...
                 0.5*i*w*(i*w - 1)*eye(2), -1.0*(M' + 2.0*i*w*R*Q)]); % step(3)
        % A11 = [MATEXP(1:2,1:2)];
        % A12 = [MATEXP(1:2,3:4)];
        A21 = [MATEXP(3:4,1:2)];
        A22 = [MATEXP(3:4,3:4)];
        % ---------- step (4) -----------% 
        % Compute the A = PDP^(-1) decomposition
        [Pk,Dk] = eig(A22); 
        % Vector that contain the eigenvalues 
        lambda_eig = Dk(sub2ind(size(Dk),1:size(Dk,1),1:size(Dk,2))); 
        % DkLog = logm(Dk);
        DkLog = zeros(size(Dk,1),size(Dk,2)); 
        n = size(DkLog,1);
        % ---------- step (5) -----------% 
        % For all eigenvalues do
        for j = 1:n 
            val_eig = lambda_eig(1,j);
            % ---------- step (6) -----------% 
            % Evaluate the complex logarithm
            dki = log(val_eig);
            % ---------- step (7) -----------%  
            % Produce the sawtooth-like function
            mki(j,k) = mod(imag(dki),pi);
            % ---------- step (8) -----------% 
            % Check whether rotation has occured
            if w == u(1,1) 
                DkLog = logm(diag(lambda_eig));
                break
            else
                if mki(j,k) - mki(j,k-1) < 0.5*pi
                    rot(j,k) = rot(j,k) + 1; % positive rotation
                elseif mki(j,k) - mki(j,k-1) < -0.5*pi
                    rot(j,k) = rot(j,k) - 1; % negative rotation
                end     
                % ---------- step (9) -----------% 
                % Compute the correct branch of the imaginary part 
                % of complex log
                IMdki = mki(j,k) + pi * rot(j,k);      
                DkLog(j,j) = real(dki) + i*IMdki;
            end
        end
        % ---------- step (10) -----------% 
        % Compute the correct complex matrix log
        A22Log = Pk * DkLog * inv(Pk);
        % Computation of matrix function A(tau)
        A = A22\A21;
        % Computation of scalar function C(tau)
        C = -0.5*beta * trace(A22Log + t*(M' + 2*R*Q)) + i*w*(r-q);
        % Characteristic Function for WMSV model
        cf(1,k) = exp(trace(A*Sigma0) + C);
    end
end


% Heston Wishart Stochastic Volatility
function cf = chf_wmsv2(u,t,r,q,M,R,Q,Sigma0,beta)
    i = complex(0,1);
    cf = zeros(1,length(u));   
    for k = 1:length(u) 
        w = u(1,k);
        MATEXP = expm(t*[M, -2.0*(Q'*Q); ...
                 0.5*i*w*(i*w - 1)*eye(2), -1.0*(M' + 2.0*i*w*R*Q)]); 
        % A11 = [MATEXP(1:2,1:2)];
        % A12 = [MATEXP(1:2,3:4)];
        A21 = [MATEXP(3:4,1:2)];
        A22 = [MATEXP(3:4,3:4)];
        % Computation of matrix function A(tau)
        A = A22\A21;
        % Computation of scalar function C(tau)
        A22Log = logm(A22);
        C = -0.5*beta * trace(A22Log + t*(M' + 2*R*Q)) + i*w*(r-q);
        % Characteristic Function for WMSV model
        cf(1,k) = exp(trace(A*Sigma0) + C);
    end
end
```